# Flip submolecule

Tags: chemfig

I am wondering, is there a way to flip a submolecule in chemfig? I know that there is a command `\vflipnext` but this applies only to the following molecule.

This is what I mean:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig,xstring}

\definesubmol{submol1}{-[1](=[:90]O)-}
\definesubmol{submol2}{-[-1](=[:-90]O)-}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{H_3C-
    (!{submol1})
    !{submol2}}

\hrule

\chemfig{!{submol1}}

\vflipnext
\chemfig{!{submol1}}
\end{document}
```

In the example above, `!submol2` is upside-down version of `!submol1`. I could not find anything in the chemfig manual. So is there a way to flip (vertically) a submolecule inside a \chemfig command? Or define a "reversed" submolecule of a different submolecule?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, your solution is already quite good: defining two versions of the molecule. As `chemfig` is built on `tikz`, I'm also not aware of a flip-functionality in Tikz. So making a modified copy is quite good. You could try hiding that in a macro (`\newcommand`, `\pic`  etc.), but I doubt the effort will pay off.